# Using SCSS variables as css keyframe percentages

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

```
@mixin fade($num:1, $fade:1, $visible:2) {

  @keyframes fade {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    #{ $a }%   { opacity: 1; }
    #{$a * ($fade + $visible)}%  { opacity: 1; }
    #{$a * ($fade + $visible + $fade)}%  { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
  }
}
```

Im getting the error `} expectedscss(css-rcurlyexpected)`

It works if i just type the percentages so I think its something to do with how im substituting the variables in

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your number to a percentage improperly.

```scss
@mixin fade($num:1, $fade:1, $visible:2) {

  @keyframes fade {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    #{($num)}%   { opacity: 1; }
    #{($num * ($fade + $visible))}%  { opacity: 1; }
    #{($num * ($fade + $visible + $fade))}%  { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
  }
}
```